# Perl script not run system command

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments

i am trying to run mplayer system command for encode video via Perl script but not working

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
`"/usr/bin/mplayer -nosound -benchmark -vo yuv4mpeg:file=>(/usr/local/bin/x264 --demuxer y4m --crf 24 --output output.h26 - 2>x264.log) input.mov"`;
```

if i run on ssh terminal

```
/usr/bin/mplayer -nosound -benchmark -vo yuv4mpeg:file=>(/usr/local/bin/x264 --demuxer y4m --crf 24 --output output.h26 - 2>x264.log) input.mov
```

command work on ssh terminal not working in perl script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have too many sets of quotes in the Perl script.  With gritted teeth, I suppose you could do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
`/usr/bin/mplayer -nosound -benchmark -vo yuv4mpeg:file=>(/usr/local/bin/x264 --demuxer y4m --crf 24 --output output.h26 - 2>x264.log) input.mov`;
```

Oooh; you've got a `bash` process redirection in there.  That complicates matters; you can't simply split the command up like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $x264 = "/usr/local/bin/x264 --demuxer y4m --crf 24 --output output.h26 - 2>x264.log";
exec "/usr/bin/mplayer", "-nosound", "-benchmark", "-vo",
      "yuv4mpeg:file=>($x264)",
      "input.mov";
```

This is often the best way to go; it isn't correct for you.

You're probably still better off using:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
system "/usr/bin/mplayer -nosound -benchmark -vo yuv4mpeg:file=>(/usr/local/bin/x264 --demuxer y4m --crf 24 --output output.h26 - 2>x264.log) input.mov";
```

since you really aren't interested in the output of the command.  OTOH, there really isn't a reason to be using Perl like this.  It would be better to write:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
/usr/bin/mplayer -nosound -benchmark -vo yuv4mpeg:file=>(/usr/local/bin/x264 --demuxer y4m --crf 24 --output output.h26 - 2>x264.log) input.mov
```

optionally with an `exec` before the command:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
exec /usr/bin/mplayer -nosound -benchmark -vo yuv4mpeg:file=>(/usr/local/bin/x264 --demuxer y4m --crf 24 --output output.h26 - 2>x264.log) input.mov
```

---

With information about the why's and wherefore's of the request trickling out, we observe:

> sh: 1: command : not found error output in perl script

The mention of `sh` indicates part of the problem.  When `bash` is run as `sh`, it does not support process substitution.  Given that this is one fragment of a bigger Perl script, we'll continue to work towards running the command from Perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $x264 = "/usr/local/bin/x264 --demuxer y4m --crf 24 --output output.h26 - 2>x264.log";
system "bash", "-c",
       "/usr/bin/mplayer -nosound -benchmark -vo yuv4mpeg:file=>($x264) input.mov";
```

Comment: If you'd tried this, why did you not mention that in the question? Why aren't you running a shell script?  I really can't see any advantage to using Perl here...

Comment: Which variant did you get the `sh: 1` information from?  Note that when run as `sh`, `bash` does not recognize process redirection.  So, you may end up having to force Perl to run `bash`.  I'll update the answer...

Comment: `sh: 1: /usr/bin/mplayer -nosound -benchmark -vo yuv4mpeg:file=>(/usr/local/bin/x264 --demuxer y4m --crf 24 --output output.h26 - 2>x264.log) input.mov: not found`

this error i getting when run in perl script

Comment: There were two Perl script fragments in my answer, and two in your question; you've not indicated which one of those generates the error message.  There are now three Perl script fragments in my answer.

Comment: Good; glad we got you on your way.